# Jquery sortable update row id-s

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have jquery sortable table:

```
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default 1" id="1">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default 2" id="2">Item 2</li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  } );
  </script>
```

Currently I can just visually drag them to edit their locations, but their id-s will remain as before relocating.

How can I edit the code so, that when a row is relocated, whole tables' id-s would be set according to the list with increasing numbers of ID-s?

Update: The sequense numbers can be in ID-s, but also in class.

Comment: When you re-order them, are you changing what the text says?  If feels like you are using an id for something it's not really intended to do.  An id should identify an element, not really it's position.

Comment: The id would be as its location in that table so that I could sort them and save the sorting to mysql later

Comment: How are you sending the data to be saved?  Because li elements are not input elements that would be sent on a form submit

Comment: Via jquery and ajax. But this is not the question, I can manage that one. The problem is still how to get the table id-s location updated when dragged. Also, the number of location can be in class, also.

Comment: If all you are after is the order, you do not need a class or an id.  That's the point I'm trying to get to

Comment: Thanks. I'll try without id-s then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to put a class or an id to track the position of the elements in the DOM.  Their position as a child element of the list IS their position.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable();
  $("#sortable").disableSelection();
  
  $('button').on('click', function(){
    var $listItems = $('#sortable li');
    
    // you can have just an array.  The order of the array IS the order
    console.log( $listItems.map(function(){ return this.innerHTML}).get() );
    
    // if you want to make it more fancy, you can put the order in the array
    console.log(
      $listItems.map(function(index, element){
        return { index: index, value: element.innerHTML };
      }).get()
    );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>
<button>Save</button>
```